# Icons are not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I am trying to integrate ionicons while it shows '?' only.

Here is the use case:

```
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';

...

<Ionicons size={20} name="star-outline" style={styles.icon} />
```

What is wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: please add more details ...

Comment: Why did you tag native-base here? Though no code related to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `star-outline` icon in `Ionicons` icon set. You should use `ios-star-outline` or `md-star-outline` or other icon sets.

> star-outlined Entypo
>
> ios-star-outline Ionicons
>
> md-star-outline Ionicons
>
> star-outline MaterialCommunityIcons

To find out more icons please visit [vector-icons directory](https://expo.github.io/vector-icons/)

**Update**

Try with below import statement

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

Comment: Yes, but when I add another one which is available it still shows '?'

Is this import statement and usage line true?

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic 4th version, you can just download the .SVG icon from https://ionicons.com/ so it could be any outline or filled or shape and after downloading (example : home-outline.SVG) move it to Your_Project\node_modules\ionicons\dist\ionicons\svg directory... and then you are Ready To Use it ... i tried and it displays the icons !